# Is there a "cancelling" drug interaction?

Tags: terminology, drug-interactions

When I read on how drugs affect organisms I often come across the drug interaction term, most often how one drug might have a good or bad synergistic effect with other drugs:

- Mixing Paracetamol with Codeine could have a better analgesic effect
- Mixing NSAID drugs (such as aspirin) with Alcohol could cause increased gastric acidity and gastrointestinal bleeding

If there is one, what is the professional term for a "cancelling" drug interaction, as when one drug might cancel the effect of another drug (not necessarily from the same chemical family by competitive binding as when both are antagonists for one another), but just "cancelling" from whatever reason?

Comment: Just a thought that maybe *antidote* is a term for that but would need corroboration.

Comment: I was thinking about this in the bus today; I personally find it an elegant opinion...